# API routes return 404 in laravel

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I have https://tenancyforlaravel.com/ installed in laravel to make multi-tenant and it works fine for the web routes.

My problem is that when I access my APIs then I get a 404 error in tenant domains.

**tenancyforlaravel documentation:** https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/routes

It says that I must put all my APIs inside `api.php` file and wrap them in a Route group with this middleware so I put all my APIs inside `api.php` file and all my APIs as below:

```
Route::middleware('tenancy')->group(function () {
    Route::name('api.')->namespace('Api')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
        ...
});
```

and when I access it using `sub.local.test/api/login` then I get 404 error.

Comment: Are you run 'php artisan optimize' command?

Comment: I did and still the same error.

Comment: Run 'php artisan route:list' and check is there this route in the routes list.

Comment: @aliheydari you do not need to run `php artisan optimize ` command, especially in development environment. It caches routes, it is not needed during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested for tenancyforlaravel.com V3 and it works OK.

```
Route::middleware([
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class
    ])->prefix('api')->group(function () {
    //
    Route::name('api.')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
        ...
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. if you have affected changes anywhere else pls share.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your API routes inside `api.php` as below

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Route::group(['prefix' => '/{tenant}',
'middleware' => [InitializeTenancyByPath::class],], 
function () {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    ...
});
```

As you haven't mentioned your tenant identifier, I am using `path` as identifier, so using `InitializeTenancyByPath` middleware. Use whatever identifier middleware you want in place of that.

Access your API routes normally as you used to do, with your identifier. As this example uses `path` as identifier, the endpoint will look like:

```
sub.local.test/api/{tenant}/login
```